# How to get ".sql" files to be searchable in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: 2013, search, crawling, sql, ifilter

What sort of black magic and secret handshakes do I need to do to get .sql files searchable with SP Foundation 2013?

Specifically, how do I get files with the ".sql" extension be both indexed and CRAWL its CONTENTS?

*I recall in 2010, you had to do a bit of hocus pocus to get PDFs working, but it worked provided you added the required adobe iFilter, and the needed registry voodoo.*

With .SQL I thought it would be easier! They are basically glorified text files, so I figured the already existing plaintext iFilter would work, but it doesn't seem to take, even after trying to tell SP to use the plaintext filter for SQL files.

**Steps I have taken:**

1. Added "sql" extension to SP via the "Manage File Types" menu in the Search Admin Panel
2. Followed the suggestions in [this MSDN Thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/eeb1fd03-a579-4665-a396-263d5a5ddf4f/ifilter-for-java-cs-sql-and-vb-files?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)
   (Maybe I made a mistake here?)

**Current Results:**

If I search for a SQL file, I have to search the complete filename for the result to show up. e.g. search "MyAmazingFile" in order to return a link to "MyAmazingFile.sql". Neither the content of the sql file, nor a partial filename will return results.

Indexer say it has indexed the SQL files correctly, and reports no warnings or errors.

Comment: did you made changes to the Registry, then restart search services and lastly full crawl?

Comment: Yes, I did this, but I havent tried PEr Jakonsen's suggestion. I will try it and report back.

Answer (score 2):

In SP2013 you also need to run New-SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormat see [HOW TO: Implement a custom iFilter in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/05/13/how-to-implement-a-custom-ifilter-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)